# Jenkins - dotnet command not found even if its installed on Raspbian

Tags: .net, jenkins, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I installed .net 6 sdk on my raspberry pi 4 (raspbian OS).
`dotnet --version` returns me a version but inside Jenkins Pipeline job command
`sh 'dotnet --version'` returns me

```
+ dotnet --version
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VoiceChannels@tmp/durable-942d9449/script.sh: 1: dotnet: not found
```

I installed .NET via `curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --channel Current` and
`echo $PATH` returns: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/.dotnet`

How do I make Jenkins know about my dotnet SDK?

Comment: It's hard for us to help you without more information. How did you install .NET? Can you share the value of `$PATH` where the `dotnet --version` command works and from within the Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: I installed a  .NET via `curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --channel Current`
`echo $PATH` returns:
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/.dotnet`

Comment: What does echo $PATH show from inside Jenkins? Is /home/pi/.dotnet included in there?

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` no dotnet.

Comment: Aha, there you go. So the $PATH is different between the two. Do you know why? What user is jenkins running as? Did you start jenkins after updating PATH or before updating path? What happens if you manually add `/home/pi/.dotnet` to $PATH within the Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: When I manually add a path it gots added but just after echoing $PATH returns the same path as it was before adding. I need somehow to set a global path that jenkins will be familiar with
Found a workaround for that. I can set `withEnv(['PATH+DOTNET=/home/pi/.dotnet']) {MY PIPELINE CODE}` and it works, but I would like to have it in PATH anyway, globally

Comment: Is Jenkins running as the user `pi` (the one with $HOME at `/home/pi`)? If so, it sounds like you started Jenkins before installing .NET, so Jenkins didn't see the updated path. If you restart Jenkins from a session/terminal where the updated $PATH is visible, Jenkins should see it too.